# Should I reinstall npm each time after I upgraded Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

It seems each time I upgraded nodejs to a new version (>0.5.6?), npm is somewhat broken (you can still use the modules already installed but you cannot update or install new modules)

This problem will go away if I do

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

So my question is: Should I reinstall npm each time I upgraded nodejs?

PS: I'm a Linux user and using [nave](https://github.com/isaacs/nave) to upgrade my nodejs.

Comment: You can also do `npm update npm -g`

Comment: when npm is broken, npm update npm -g won't work :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to 0.6.3, each time you install a new version of Node you will need to install npm for that installed instance, even if you installed over the top of a previous version (probably not a good idea).

Starting with 0.6.3, npm is bundled with Node.

Comment: is that means the Node bundled version of npm is not compatible (or not sync) with npmjs.org default version?

Comment: That isn't known yet. I suspect that the bundled npm will be upgradable. It may be worth asking the question here: http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/d592e5f194588aa7/3d43cd9d88b4ebf1?lnk=gst&q=npm#3d43cd9d88b4ebf1

Comment: Question on this even though it's old. I very recently upgraded to node 6.11. npm still at 1.1.0-2. Upgrading npm manually I get 1.1.2. Seems strange no? There are posts older than my upgrade talking about having to install 1.1.0-3 so there's something wrong here.

Comment: I would need to look at the what version of NPM was bundled with 0.6.11. 0.6.12 does have a new version of NPM with it.